# Unmarked cached assests in the Chrome Dev tool

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools, browser-cache, cache-control

I have web page where a few cached assets are marked as cached (i.e here is **from disk cache**)

[image: cached assests marked as cached]

but seeing blow screen shot , dozens of other cached assests(e.g react ,jQuery) are neither marked as **304 status** code nor the **cached from disk/from memory cache,etc.**

As to their actual size ,they are undoubtedly from cache , how come these cached files are not marked cached?

[image: cached assests marked as cached]

Answer (score 0):

This weird case disappears after cleaning of the cache of chrome browser and **304 status** code for those cached assets are shown now as expected.